Automatically updated created_by/updated_by with Django authenticated user
I have a BaseModel that looks like this:
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='+', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, db_column='updated_by')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='+', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, db_column='created_by')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


I want to automatically update the updated_by and created_by fields.  But I don't have access to the request object.  How can I get the user?

How about using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL or get_user_model()? The second one could throw exception telling that the module is not installed yet but first one would work as expected.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

IT is not even said that there is a user, since you can also create model objects with a management command: the model layer is deliberately separated from requests to prevent writing view logic in the model.

So how is this functionality typically implemented?  Does every endpoint need to just ensure that those fields are updated?

@PeterKronenberg: typically a mixin is used, for example in the (class-based) view or serializer.

Can you point me to an example?  I'm new to Django.  I'm using function view, not class-based

See https://pypi.org/project/django-currentuser/
